# SQLite and a Custom ListView. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

---

EDITED with a bit more information:

Here is the database schema:

```
 private static final String SQL_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        COLUMN_WINE_NAME + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_WINE_PRICE + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_WINE_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_WINE_TEMP + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_WINE_STORE + " TEXT);";
```

---

So I'm making a list where I want each row to just have the name and the description.

The data is coming from an SQLite database that the app makes. The data is correctly in the database.

The issue is that currently I am getting an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jeremy.sqlwine/com.example.jeremy.sqlwine.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

Which is weird because that column definitely does exist in the database.

I just feel a bit lost at the moment. I've looked up a bunch of guides and watched some youtube tutorials on this stuff but I can't quite connect the dots.

Can I get some guidance please?

Here are the relevant activities.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
WineCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intentGoToAdd = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentGoToAdd);
        }
    });
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    SQLiteDatabase db = mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    ListView wineListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    wineListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

    //Selecting what details I want to put into each row in the list (just the name and the description)
    String[] projection ={
            WineContract.WineEntry.COLUMN_WINE_NAME,
            WineContract.WineEntry.COLUMN_WINE_DESCRIPTION,};

    //This should select only the current cursor's name and description columns
    Cursor cursor = db.query(WineContract.WineEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null, null,null);

    mCursorAdapter = new WineCursorAdapter(this, cursor);
    wineListView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_deleteDB) {
        mDatabaseHelper.deleteDatabase();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Database deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        onResume();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

The Cursor adapter:

```
public class WineCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public WineCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    //Populate the views
    TextView textViewName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wineName);
    TextView textViewDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wineDescription);

    //get the info from cursor
    String wineName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(WineContract.WineEntry.COLUMN_WINE_NAME));
    String wineDescription = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(WineContract.WineEntry.COLUMN_WINE_DESCRIPTION));

    textViewName.setText(wineName);
    textViewDescription.setText(wineDescription);
}
```

}

WineContract:

```
public class WineContract {

public WineContract() {
}

public static class WineEntry implements BaseColumns{

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "wines";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_WINE_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String COLUMN_WINE_PRICE = "PRICE";
    public static final String COLUMN_WINE_DESCRIPTION = "DESCRIPTION";
    public static final String COLUMN_WINE_TEMP = "TEMP";
    public static final String COLUMN_WINE_STORE = "STORE";

}
```

}

And here is the list_item (what each row in the list contains) xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="16dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/wineName"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textSize="16dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/wineDescription"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="16dp"/>
```

Comment: can you paste your database schema or screenshot? Also, remove the application from the device and test it again.

Comment: The `Cursor` must have the `_id` column to work with a `CursorAdapter`. Your `projection` does not include that column.

Comment: @MaihanNijat I just edited the post with the schema of the database. And I have tried uninstalling and trying it again. The same thing happens.

Comment: @MikeM. I just tried adding the COLUMN_ID to the projection of the cursor that is on the MainActivity, but I'm getting the same error yet.

Comment: Well then. To fix that specific issue I just had to go back to the Contract class and change"public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_ID"; to  "public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";". Now to figure out how to get the listview to see the cursor items...

Comment: Have you, since, uninstalling, added any data? Perhaps add a line after getting the Cursor to display the number of rows e.g. `Log.d("CSRCOUNT","Cursor has " + Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()) + " rows.");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue.

For some reason, Android Studio looks specifically for "_id". I had to change this line of code:

```
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_ID";
```

to

```
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
```

And that fixed the issue. I swear I've done _ID before and it worked. But either way, it's working now.

Hopefully this helps anyone with the same issue!